# Select Data using DateRange in SQL

Tags: sql

I am querying in my Table for Distinct Product Details. Now I have to filter Data based upon Date Column present in Table. The column having Dates have Data Type Varchar2. But I am not getting any result whereas Data is present in that Daterange. WEEK_DATE is my Date Column.

```
select distinct PRODUCT
from Table1
where WEEK_DATE between '12/31/2012' and '06/19/2017'
```

Some Sample Dates

```
2014-03-31
2014-09-01
2014-12-15
2014-12-22
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by switching to standard date formats:

```
select distinct product
from Table1
where week_date >= '2012-12-31' and
      week_date < '2017-06-20';
```

This will probably fix your problem.  You query would return no rows if the comparisons were made as strings rather than dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query :

```
select distinct PRODUCT from Table1
where cast(WEEK_DATE as date) between '12/31/2012' and '06/19/2017'
```